# How can Iterate a Nested Json in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to use this nested URL of firebase where I have to send the `range` key to the next activity.the range key may have multiple items. but I don't understand how to use the nested URL with the `addChildEventListener()`

```
{
item1: { details: "5x shirts Washed,Ironed and Hunged", 
         name: "High Five",
         oldprice: 71,
         price: 23,
         product: {range: {
                     item1: {
                     details: "5x shirts,washed, Ironed and Hunged",
                     name: "High Five",
                     price : 2.6
                            }
                          },
         title: "We're specialists at caring for a wide range of shirt  styles,including formal dress shirts and laid-back styles"
                  }
       }
item2: { name: "Shirts",
         price: 45
       },
item3: {
         name: "Blouses",
         price: 6
       },
item4: {
         name: "t-Shirts",
         price: 34
       }
}
```

Comment: it starts from the product key

Comment: you need to use valueventlistener for that